Property values based on the key in object
Can I somehow restrict the "value" to be the same as the object key?
const obj = {
  dog: {
    value: "dog"
  },
  cat: {
    value: "cat"
  }
}


You can strict the types:
type AnimalKeys = 'dog' | 'cat'; 

type AnimalObject<T extends string> = {
  [K in T]: {
    value: K;
  }
}

and if you use:
const obj: AnimalObject<AnimalKeys> = {
  dog: {
    value: "dog",
  },
  cat: {
    value: "cat",
  },

  // cat: { value: "dog" }  // Error: value should be "cat"
};


You could use a generic helper function:
Playground
const makeKeyedObj = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: {[X in K]:{value: X}}) => obj;

const obj = makeKeyedObj({
  dog: {
    value: "dog"
  },
  cat: {
    value: "cat"
  }
});

